# What is the proper way of aborting a build using Cake?

Tags: cakebuild

Using the `Error()` method only logs an error. But what if I want to abort the build? I can throw an exception to abort the build but it does not seem right. So is there a proper way to abort?

```
var releaseNotes = ParseReleaseNotes("./ReleaseNotes.md");

if(releaseNotes.Version.ToString() != nugetVersion)
{
    Error("Release notes are missing an entry for v{0}. Latest release notes are for v{1}", nugetVersion, releaseNotes.Version);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Error` method is just a convenience method for logging an error. I understand the confusion though.

If something is wrong with that you cannot recover from, you should throw an exception to indicate it. The Cake script runner will then log the error (using the `Error` method) and return exit code 1 to indicate that something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer is to throw an exception and not use the `Error()` method like this:

```
var releaseNotes = ParseReleaseNotes("./ReleaseNotes.md");

if(releaseNotes.Version.ToString() != nugetVersion)
{
    throw new Exception("Release notes are missing an entry for v{0}. Latest release notes are for v{1}", nugetVersion, releaseNotes.Version);        
}
```